# Spring Boot SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() return null on basic auth

Tags: spring-boot

I have a problem doing my first filter and checking the SecurityContextHolder.getContext (). GetAuthentication () returns null.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ConfigSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
private final TokenHeader tokenHeader;
private final UserService userService;

public ConfigSecurity(ApplicationUserService applicationUserService,
                      PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                      TokenHeader tokenHeader,
                      UserService userService) {
    this.applicationUserService = applicationUserService;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.tokenHeader = tokenHeader;
    this.userService = userService;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/token/refresh").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new TokenHeaderFilter(this.tokenHeader,this.userService), 
   BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(this.applicationUserService);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder);
    return provider;
 }
```

my filter

```
public class TokenHeaderFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

private final TokenHeader tokenHeader;
private final UserService userService;

@Autowired
public TokenHeaderFilter(TokenHeader tokenHeader, UserService userService) {
    this.tokenHeader = tokenHeader;
    this.userService = userService;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse servletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    String header = servletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    System.out.println(authentication);
}
```

On Debug:

[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6FBK.png)

If you need me to show some more class, you can tell me and in the same way debug, this problem is already happening to me 3 times one day it works and for the other it stops working

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775663/how-to-load-a-custom-daoauthenticationprovider-into-the-spring-context

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but it did not help to find a request, I also have my daoprovides declared in the first code where I pass my passwordecoder and userservice